How to replace a line with another in .bashrc
I have a line like this
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '

I want it to be replaced by
PS1='\[\033[01;34m\][TEST]\[\033[00m\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '

so that I can show the environment label. How should I do it. I tried sed commands but I can't make it right because of the quotes and slashes.
Can I get some light on this ?
PS: I need to retain the old value of PS1 and I only need to append the environment label information.

Open the file in a text editor, remove the line and paste the new one?

Unless you need to make the change to hundreds of different .bashrc files, just edit the file manually with the text editor of your choice. (I would also be defining PS1 dynamically using PROMPT_COMMAND at this point.)

@chepner I am trying to create a script that do this change to multiple servers.

@0stone0 I am trying to automate it so that I can update in multiple servers.

Please add all requested information or clarification to your question. Do you need to keep some variable content of the old PS1 value or can you simply replace a line PS1=anything with a constant new value. If you need to keep parts of the old value, explain the details in the question.

@JITHIN_PATHROSE You can just copy a single locally edited version to the other servers.

@Bodo I need the retain the value in PS1. I need to append the environment label info to this.

echo "export PS1=\[\033[01;34m\][TEST]\[\033[00m\]$PS1" >> ~/.bashrc

Please [edit] your question and explain how exactly you want to modify the existing value in your question. Please don't use comments to add requested information or clarification. I suggest to write something like "before/after ABC insert/append XYZ". If there are different values for PS1, show at least 2 different examples and the expected result.

Basic rule: every backslash needs to be backslashed, as does every left square bracket and dollar sign. A single quotes needs to be quoted for the shell, too.
sed 's/^PS1='\''\${debian_chroot:+(\$debian_chroot)}\\\[\\033\[01;32m\\\]\\u@\\h\\\[\\033\[00m\\\]:\\\[\\033\[01;34m\\\]\\w\\\[\\033\[00m\\\]\\\$ '\''$/PS1='\''\\[\\033[01;34m\\][TEST]\\[\\033[00m\\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\\[\\033[01;32m\\]\\u@\\h\\[\\033[00m\\]:\\[\\033[01;34m\\]\\w\\[\\033[00m\\]\\$ '\''/'

